# Show current sub menu and hide the other ones

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to make the current submenu stay active and the other ones to hide, but failing to understand how the `this` keyword works. Currently all the sub-menu stays active when a link from any submenu is clicked because of the `$('.nav-second-level').show();` and I think here I need to modify but can't understand how. I am a jquery Noob.

HTML

```
<li>
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-cog fa-fw"></i> Administration<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
    <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
        <li>
            <a href="admin-users.php">Users</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="admin-groups.php">Groups</a>
        </li>
    </ul><!-- /.nav-second-level -->
</li>
<li>
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-cog fa-fw"></i> ANother Submenu<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
    <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
        <li>
            <a href="another-link.php">More Users</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="another-link.php"> MoreGroups</a>
        </li>
    </ul><!-- /.nav-second-level -->
</li>
```

JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var aObj = $('a');
    var found = false;
    for(var i=aObj.length-1; i>=1 && !found; i--) {
        if(document.location.href.indexOf(aObj[i].href)>=0) {
            $(aObj[i]).addClass('active-me');
            found = true;
        }
    }
    var submenulink = $('.nav-second-level > li > a');
    if(submenulink.hasClass('active-me') == true){
        $('.nav-second-level').show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // hide all second level
    $('.nav-second-level').hide();

    // show all second level whose anchor has matching href
    $('a').each(function(){
      if(document.location.href.indexOf($(this).attr('href')) > 0)
      {
        // add class to matching anchor
        $(this).addClass('active-me');
        // find its parent 'nav-second-level' and make visible
        $(this).closest('.nav-second-level').show();
      }

    });

    // open submenu on click of main menu
    $('a[href="#"]').click(function(){
       $('.nav-second-level').hide();
       $(this).next('.nav-second-level').show();
    });
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/64QpR/143/)**

Comment: Makes the entire links with class active-me and all sub-menus visible

Comment: what is value of `document.location.href` in your case, cause here you are just checking matching value and not exact value.

Comment: I have missed `if(.. > 0)` comparision with zero in if condition. Sorry my bad, I just copied from your code and paste it. Please try with updated answer. Also added demo link :)

Comment: Almost working perfectly, just that when I try to open the other submenu it doesn't let me, I am using this: http://pastebin.com/FBg19GJ1. And after this code(plugin), i have the code posted on stackoverflow. Thanks a lot for helping me.

Comment: do you want to open other submenu when click on main menu?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58233/discussion-between-user3467855-and-bhushan-kawadkar).